# Python 2.7 - b'' appears in front of a string in output file

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding

I wrote a Python script running a SQL query and creating an external file from the output.
It works well on my computer but when I try to run the exact same script on another computer the output file is different.

In mine the content of the content of the output file looks like this : FR, DE, CA
and with the other computer it looks like this: b'FR', b'DE', b'CA'

There is this b'' around the string and I don't know what I should configure in the 2nd computer to remove that. Both computers are using Python 2.7.11.

I noticed the b'' thing appears in the 2nd computer after I use the function: smart_str from django.utils.encoding
Before I pass the string to the output file I do:  str(x)  but the b'' is not removed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: That sounds like you're not really using Python 2.7.

Comment: The `b` indicate a bytes object.  That is a single-byte character string, which Python 2 uses, rather than a multi-byte character string which Python 3 uses.  Are you sure this is not Python 3?  Call `decode()` method to convert to a string, e.g. `x = x.decode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this in my code

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')

then removed the function str() before the output of my string and now it works fine, thanks!